# javascript dependent drop down with doctrine form element

Tags: javascript, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i'm trying to do a drop down list using javascript jquery.
With zend framework2 and doctrine i rendered html elements as follows:

```
<div>           
Country<select name="country"><option value="">--select Country-</option>
<option value="1" class="country" id="country">Greater Accra</option>
<option value="2" class="country" id="country">Ashanti</option>
<option value="3" class="country" id="country">Central</option>
<option value="4" class="country" id="country">Eastern</option></select>           
</div>

<div>       
States<select name="states"><option value="">--select States--</option>
<option value="1" class="states" id="states" data-id="1">Roman      Ridge</option>
<option value="2" class="states" id="states" data-id="2">Kumasi</option>
<option value="3" class="states" id="states" data-id="3">Cape Coast</option>
<option value="4" class="states" id="states" data-id="4">Koforidua</option>
<option value="5" class="states" id="states" data-id="1">Accra</option>
<option value="6" class="states" id="states" data-id="3">Moree</option>
<option value="7" class="states" id="states" data-id="1">Chantan</option>
<option value="8" class="states" id="states" data-id="1">Achimota</option>
<option value="9" class="states" id="states" data-id="2">Mampong</option>
<option value="10" class="states" id="states" data-id="1">Lapaz</option></select>           
</div>
```

and this is my jquery fuction

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var s1 = $('#country');
var s2 = $('#states');

var dependantOptions = s2.find('option');
dependantOptions.css('visibility', 'hidden');

s1.on('change', function() {
dependantOptions.css('visibility', 'hidden');
s2.find("option[data-id='" + $(this).val() + "']").css('visibility',     'visible');
});

});
</script>
```

i cant figure out why the javascript function isn't working.
i hope to find an answer soon. thanks

Comment: Your `select`s don't actually have css ids

Answer (score 0):

Your select list have only the attributes `name="country"` and `name="states"` and no corresponding ids. You search like this:

```
var s1 = $('#country');
var s2 = $('#states');
```

So you should add the ids `id="country"` and `id="states"`.